# missing french char while using itextpdf

Tags: java, sql, itext

```
pdfCellLeft(new Paragraph("Numéro Téléphone :"),table);
private void pdfCellLeft(Paragraph p,PdfPTable table)
{   
  PdfPCell cell=new PdfPCell(p);
  cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
  cell.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(51, 105, 255));
  cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
  table.addCell(cell);
}
```

[Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v7rg.png)[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAEGd.png)

while using the text most special characters are missing like é is missing and other things

Comment: I've never used other characters when I use iText, but this kb might help with the issue you're having https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-use-cyrillic-characters-in-a-pdf

Comment: yes but it will be long procedure to put Unicode value for every single symbol

Comment: Have you tried `BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(font, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);`? Can you attach a more self-contained code sample that one can run? Any reason for not using iText 7?